# Set variable as empty string in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How can I set variable as empty string in logic apps?

If I set no value in Value field I get "Error: Failed to save logic app. Definition contains invalid parameters."
[image]

If I set quotationmarks in Value field, I get a pair of escaped quotationmarks in output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the empty value you need go to the `Code view` and set the value to `" "`(double quotation marks with a blank space) like below picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not exactly empty value as there is a single whitespace presumably, but it works for me. Thanks :)

Comment: You can actually go to codeview and set Value as empty and save it, and get empty strings that way. But you cannot save changes in logic app designer from then on, so not exactly ideal...

Comment: So you have to use the quotation marks with a blank space or set the empty value as the last step of your design.

Comment: And if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround is to set it to trim(' ')

Comment: This worked fabulously, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Set it to another var initialised which was set as null (no value)